# Openwhisk distributed setup

Tags: openwhisk

I want to install a distributed openwhisk instance on-prem on ubuntu 16.04
For this if create two open whisk instance pointing to same counchdb and a load balancer above nginx. for routing the traffic to each instance. will this setup work or there would be more challenges to it than i think ?

Answer (score 2):

There are more challenges, like the in-memory caching used by OpenWhisk's controller as of today.

For a truly distributed setup, you can refer to [the distributed deployment documentation](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/ansible/README_DISTRIBUTED.md). Some components won't scale up naturally as of today, but that's [being actively worked on](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/pull/2205).

Comment: Thanks  i will try with two different ubuntu VMs lets c wat happens

Comment: ./ansible/environments/distributed/hosts this file i will have to mention the IPs that the installation will happen correct? i mean the two VMs that are used for distributed setup